As a registrar, how to find unjudged indentities in the indentity pallet?
If I am a registrar, how can I find the judgements that I need/can judge?
As far as I know there is not storage that provides that inforamtion. How the registrar can know what indetity has to be judeged? It appers to me that the process involves a off chain communication. This sounds weird for me because it feels that it should be possible to do it fully on chain.

Query this storage. Find the judgements field. If your registrar index doesn't appear there, that means you haven't make a judgement for they.

And if the field shows:
[your_registrar_index, FeePaid(fee_amount)]

Which means someone has requested a judgement from you.
Also, if you don't want to query the storage you can monitor the on-chain event JudgementRequested.
https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/aaf0443591b134a0da217d575161872796e75059/substrate/frame/identity/src/lib.rs#L366
Or from Subscan API, theGraph and etc.

But currently, to verify a person's info without any other infrastructures, I still believe it needs off-chain communication.

While I’d love to use the storage method, it’s impractical for fetching unjudged identities. To identify unjudged identities, I would need to fetch the entire storage, which is inefficient. For instance, if there are 10,000 identities and only 1 is unjudged, fetching all is impractical. If an event is missed or I dont want to listen to them, I am forced to query the whole storage each time.

We are building a frontend where a registrar can log in and judge. The frontend is not continuously online and is not listening to events.

theGraph best fits your requirements

A better way is probably to set up an idexer like Xavier mentioned. https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/11667/3577
But there is another quicker workaround. Our chain has forked the identity pallet and allows extensions. I have implemented a storage map that stores all unjudged identities:
#[pallet::storage]
#[pallet::getter(fn unjudged_identities)]
pub(super) type UnjudgedIdentities<T: Config> = StorageMap<_, Twox64Concat, T::AccountId, (), OptionQuery>;

...

pub fn request_judgement(
   ...
   // at the end of the function
   <UnjudgedIdentities<T>>::insert(&sender, ());
   ...
)

pub fn provide_judgement(
   ...
   // at the end of the function
   <UnjudgedIdentities<T>>::remove(&target);
   ...
)

Or a solution that can track the identities by registrar index:
#[pallet::storage]
#[pallet::getter(fn unjudged_identities)]
pub(super) type UnjudgedIdentities<T: Config> = StorageDoubleMap<
    _,
    Twox64Concat,
    RegistrarIndex,
    Twox64Concat,
    T::AccountId,
    (),
    OptionQuery,
>;

...

pub fn request_judgement(
   ...
   // at the end of the function
   <UnjudgedIdentities<T>>::insert(reg_index, sender.clone(), ());
   ...
)

pub fn provide_judgement(
   ...
   // at the end of the function
   <UnjudgedIdentities<T>>::remove(reg_index, target.clone());
   ...
)

